# MVC WebAPI model binding issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i m facing an issue, need bit of help

i have request in webapi that has model in request

```
public HttpResponseMessage Update(MyRequest req)

class MyRequest{
public string UserName {get; set;}
public CustomEnum Type {get; set;}
}

Enum CustomEnum {
Registered ,
UnRegistered
}
```

problem is in my request i m seding an enum value which is not part of CustomEnum but as WEBAPI itself maps values it gives me exception  of not found

so i thought why not when request arrives i map it myself like

```
class MyRequest{
public string {get; set;}
public CustomEnum {
get { 
 if ( ??? = "NEWVALUE" )  ??? = "Registered";
return {???} ; set;}
}
```

issue is i m unable to get ??? this value in get accessor , can some one help me how to get it

Comment: Could you please show us a more of your code: Update controller, maybe model binder

Comment: well this is almost all code . Update(MyRequest req) is in Controller , i m sending request through postMan and WEB do model binding itself thats where the issue

Comment: if some how i can get value in Get accessor of My Request class then i can do if else thats what i m trying to do

Comment: show an example of your request - what are you passing as the enum value - string, or the equivalent int value?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are essentialy trying to bind a value to `CustomEnum` type, which is not any of defined values of that `enum` - so the value cannot be bound to the property which, I would assume, is the reason for the exception.

What I think you could do instead, is something like:

```
class MyRequest{
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
    pulic CustomEnum? TypeAsEnum 
    { 
        get{
            CustomEnum value;
            return Enum.TryParse(typeof(CustomEnum), out value) ? value : (CustomEnum?)null; 
        }
    }
}
```

Then I think that any value should be bindable to the Type property (since it is a `string`) and you could use `TypeAsEnum` property to get a `CustomEnum` type value or null if the `Type` cannot be converted to the `CustomEnum` type. You can still obtain the textual representation of the value from the `Type` property in any case.